# Navigate to page in ShellPage.xaml.cs caused exception

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using [WindowsTemplateStudio](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio), In ShellPage.xaml.cs, I want to detect if the user changed network, app navigate to a specified page.

So I used

```
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Connectivity.NetworkHelper.Instance.NetworkChanged += Instance_NetworkChanged;
private async void Instance_NetworkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //NavigationService.Navigate(page);
   shellFrame.Navigate(typeof(page));
}
```

But this caused System.Exception.
How to handle this, and navigate to a page, thx.

Comment: Tell some more about the exception. Message, StackTrace, etc...

Comment: Please try to call `Navigate` method in UI thread that use `Dispatcher.RunAsync`.

Comment: Yes, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Navigate to page in ShellPage.xaml.cs caused exception

The problem is `NetworkChanged` invoked in un-uithread, but `Navigate` method need uithread environment. So please call `Dispatcher` in NetworkChanged event handler.

```
private async void Instance_NetworkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
  {
    shellFrame.Navigate(typeof(page));
  });
}
```